# PHP session ... how unique are they?

Tags: php, wordpress, session

Things like wordpress store the session id in a cookie. I got to wondering / looking around about how predictable this id is, and how unique they are.

From what Ive read, theyre very, very unpredictable, and almost certainly unique.

Is that correct?

Comment: The real question is, how many users will visit your site within the expiry time of a session?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know that you may get a duplicate session id in PHP however the chances of getting the duplicate session id is very very rare.

Also note that the session id in PHP is based on a hash(MD5) which contains IP address of the client,Current time,PHP Linear Congruence Generator - a pseudo random number generator (PRNG)
and OS-specific random source.

> As of PHP 5.4.0 session.entropy_file defaults to /dev/urandom or
>   /dev/arandom if it is available. In PHP 5.3.0 this directive is left
>   empty by default.

Comment: If, say, I were storing session IDs in a database, I should make sure its unique first, and if not, roll another then, right?

Comment: @jason:- Yes, I have updated my answer as to how it is generated and as you will see that the chances of getting the same unique id would be very rare. So I doubt you will every get a chance of rolling! :)